# Sum specify rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a summary for my data and worked out percentages of occurrences per category.
Now, I want to sum a subset of categories to show their value combined. For example, I want to be able to say that 51.1% of all occurrences are within the categories 30, 60, and 120 days (sum of rows #6, #9, and #3). The name of the Data.frame is "Summary_2".

```
 Category Count Percent
1    1 day     4    3.3%
8   5 days     5    4.1%
4 180 days     8    6.5%
5 240 days     9    7.3%
2  10 days    15   12.2%
3 120 days    18   14.6%
6  30 days    19   15.4%
7 360 days    19   15.4%
9  60 days    26   21.1%
```

This is a summary of tickets. I arbitrarily want to say that 50% of our tickets are resolved within 2 months, 30% are resolved from 180 to 360 days, and 20% is resolved within 10 days.

In Excel it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Two of your three fields appear to be strings, have you thought about how to make them numbers?

Comment: How are you choosing *those* rows? They aren't the min or max of category (even account for fixing your number problem), they aren't the min/max of percent (ditto), it is not clear how you intend to group the rows much less add them up. Please [edit] your question to add more context, and please show what code you've tried so far.

Comment: @r2evans I am really a novice in R. Trying to figure that out in the last 2 hours. I want to arbitrarily sum up 2 or 3 categories together.
It is a data frame. I created it as a summary of my data.

Comment: `sum(as.numeric(gsub("[^.0-9]", "", dat$Percent[ dat$Category %in% c("30 days", "60 days", "120 days") ])))`

Comment: Greetings. It would be great if you could share a reproducible dataset rather than a picture or a table. You can share the `dput` of your data by following the steps in this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg